# Storing invoices in a database

Tags: sql, database, normalization

I am making a piece of invoicing software and I want it to save each individual invoice.

The user creates invoices by selecting a customer, as well as however many items are being billed to the customer. Seeing as most invoices will have multiple items, what is the best way to save them to the database without being incredibly redundant? I'm willing to rearrange my entire database if need be.

My tables look like this:

Customers Table:

```
Id        / Primary key
FullName
Address
Phone
```

Items Table (a table of products offered):

```
Id        / Primary key
ItemName
Price
Description
```

Invoices Table (saved invoices):

```
Id        / Primary key
CustId    / Foreign key is Id in Customer table
ItemId    / Foreign key is Id in Item table
Notes
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need another table to store invoices (what you call `Invoices` now actually stores *invoice items*).

```
Customer
    id
    name
    etc.

Item
    id
    name
    etc.

Invoice
    id
    cust_id
    date

InvoiceItem
    id
    inv_id
    item_id
```

This is the classic way of modeling a [*many to many* relationship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29) using a junction table (i.e. `InvoiceItem`).

Comment: So if the user has multiple invoice items, each one gets stored as a separate entry in the Invoice Items table? And all items belonging to the invoice with have the same InvoiceId?

Comment: @ToddBauer Correct. For each invoice there will be an `Invoice` record with an ID. For each item on each invoice you will create an `InvoiceItem` that connects the item to the invoice. It is common to have a `quantity` column to `InvoiceItem`, in case multiple identical items can be added to the invoice.

Comment: Excellent! I will add a quantity row as well. And off topic, I wanted to tell you that you're well-spoken and clear in your explanations, and I appreciate your time and effort. Answer: selected. Keep fighting the good fight.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you will actually want a 4th table to join them. To normalize your data, only keep on each line things that are specific to that invoice

Invoices table

```
Id        / Primary key
CustId    / Foreign key is Id in Customer table
Notes
```

Invoice Items table

```
InvoiceId
ItemId
```